# glDrawArrays not drawing correctly

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, opengl

I made a painting program. Everything works as I expected. But while drawing, sometimes some strange things happen.

I run app, and press left mouse button on image. It should draw point from code:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, brushTextura);
glPointSize(100);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0,GLVertices);
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, count);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

at point where I press. `mouseDown` registers mouseDown location, converts it to NSValue, sends to array, and then before drawing I extract NSValue to CGPoint and send it to GLfloat so that it could be drawn by glDrawArrays. But no matter where I click the mouse on the image it draws the point at coordinates (0,0). After that every thing works OK. See image:

[image: mouse click]

This was first problem. The second problem is that when I paint with it (drag pressed mouse), sometimes points appear where they are not drawn. Image:

[image: mouse drag]

When I continue drag it disappears. After some dragging it appears again and disappears again. And so on. Image:

[image]

Any Ideas why it could happen? I will post code bellow:

---

Mouse down:

```
- (void) mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event
{
    location = [self convertPoint: [event locationInWindow] fromView:self];
    NSValue *locationValue = [NSValue valueWithPoint:location];
    [vertices addObject:locationValue];

        [self drawing];
}
```

Mouse dragged:

```
- (void) mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)event
{
    location = [self convertPoint: [event locationInWindow] fromView:self];
    NSValue *locationValue = [NSValue valueWithPoint:location];
    [vertices addObject:locationValue];

        [self drawing];
}
```

Drawing:

```
- (void) drawing {
int count = [vertices count] * 2;
NSLog(@"count: %d", count);
int currIndex = 0;
GLfloat *GLVertices = (GLfloat *)malloc(count * sizeof(GLfloat));
for (NSValue *locationValue in vertices) {
    CGPoint loc = locationValue.pointValue;
    GLVertices[currIndex++] = loc.x;
    GLVertices[currIndex++] = loc.y;    
 }
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, brushTextura);
glPointSize(100);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, GLVertices);
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, count);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are setting your `count` variable (the one used in `glDrawArrays`) to `[vertices count] * 2`, which seems strange.

The last argument to `glDrawArrays` is the number of vertices to draw, whereas in your code it seems you are setting it to double the number (maybe you thought it's the number of floats?), which means you are just drawing rubbish after the first `count` vertices.

Comment: If i change it to `[vertices count]`, then it breaks when i start drawing. Few points being drawn ok, and after that it show error:  
`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=13, adress=0x0)`  at  `glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, count);` or at   `NSValue *locationValue = [NSValue valueWithPoint:vieta];` error  `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`. One time one error, other time other error. I don't know why, but error is not the same all the time

Comment: And sometimes at break it shows message in console:  `OGL(896,0x7fff79c93960) malloc: *** error for object 0x100151a98: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug`

Comment: @JuliusPetraška The reason is probably that you also use it in the `malloc` for `GLVertices`, so the vertex array is too small and you are once again reading too many vertices (only this time resulting in a crash). Of course the `GLVertices` array has to have a size of `[vertices count] * 2`, because it contains 2 floats for each vertex. But then you only have to draw `[vertices count]` complete vertices in `glDrawArrays`.

Comment: Thank you very much

P.S. I can't award you with bounty now. It says i have to wait 23 hours

Answer (score 1):

The fact the vertices aren't rendered in the exact location you clicked on should be a hint the problem is you've not properly determined the hit point within the view.

Your code has:

```
location = [self convertPoint: [event locationInWindow] fromView: self];
```

which tells the view to convert the point from its coordinates (self) to the same view's coordinates (self), even though the point is actually relative to the window.

To convert the point from the window's coordinates to the view, change that line to the following:

```
location = [self convertPoint: [event locationInWindow] fromView: nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to glDrawArrays are defined as (GLenum mode, GLint first, GLsizei count).

The second arguments defines the first index of the vertex attributes used when drawing. You're passing 1 as the first index which makes your vertex coordinates unmatch. I assume that you want 0 there.

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawArrays.xml